# Calculating best-case, worse-case Complexity

Tags: python, big-o, computer-science

If I have a function that is quadratic complexity, i.e. the runtime is directly proportional to the square of the input size.  How would I identify its best or worse case runtime, specifically how do I determine if the best and worst case are the same?

Comment: I don't understand why this is even a question. If the function always takes n² time, it's clearly n² best-case and worst-case, right? What am I missing?

Comment: you need to show your function then only we can compute its best, avg and worst time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This really **depends on your algorithm and your input data**. For example
a search algorithm can have a typically runtime of O(x^2) but in certain situations this differs:

- Typically runtime is for statistically random data (normal case)
- If the input data is already sorted (best case), then it depends on the algorithm if it still has normal runtime or is faster e.g. O(1)
- If the input data is shaped explicitly in the worst order that there is possible for this specific algorithm (but not very likely), then it may have a bigger worst-case O-notation

**Which algorithm you choose** then depends on your use case:

- If the data is most likely already sorted or partially sorted: You may go with an algorithm that has better best case runtime
- If you want fastest results in most cases (with unsorted data): You go for best normal case
- If your algorithm may kill someone if it takes to long (e.g. dealing with malicious user input): You will choose one which as equal normal/worst case runtime